# Integrate AWS secret Manager to Jboss and Tomcat servers to retrieve database credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, jboss, aws-secrets-manager

I have deployed project WAR files in both Tomcat and Jboss servers and database source is fetched through JNDI.

Following are the sample DB configuration defined in server containers.
I have hardcoded database credentials in those files.

**Jboss 7 daatabase configuration defined in configuration xml file**

```
<datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/test" pool-name="test" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>60</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>abc</user-name>
                        <password>abc123</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>35</idle-timeout-minutes>
                        <query-timeout>300</query-timeout>
                    </timeout>
                </datasource>
 <datasources>
```

**Tomcat 8 database configurations in conf/context.xml**

```
 <Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

<Resource name="datasource/test" auth="Container"
                type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                    factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
                        user="abc"
                        password="abc123"
                        jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jacplus"
                        driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                        minPoolSize="2"
                        initialPoolSize="30"
                        maxPoolSize="50"
                        idleConnectionTestPeriod="600"
                        acquireRetryAttempts="30"/>
                        
 </Context>
```

As a security concern, I got a requirement to move these hardcoded credentials to AWS secret Manager and retrieve them in runtime.
All posts I have seen mention using the API/SDK directly from code, none I have found say anything about server integration.

My question is there a way to integrate AWS secret manager to both tomcat and JBoss application servers and use data source as JNDI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can AWS Secret Manager be accessed from Tomcat using JNDI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59386005/can-aws-secret-manager-be-accessed-from-tomcat-using-jndi)

Comment: Another related question: [How to pass the DB AWS secret into tomcat context.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64440020/11748454)

Comment: how is your tomcat deployed? I assume its in AWS? possible a docker image? In which case, you can passed in secrets as parameters when starting up.